# Al refrescar pagina se vuelven a enviar datos a la base de datos

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Tengo un problema estoy usando java web 8  con servlets, estoy haciendo un registro de usuarios desde la vista se envian al controlador (Servelet), mi problema es que despues de registrado si refresco la pagina lso datos ingresados anteriormente vuelve y entran al controlador y se duplican en la base datos cada vez que refresco la pagina. A que se debe esto y como podria evitarlo.
Gracias por la atencion.

mi codigo del servlet empieza asi.

```
  // IDS SOLO PARA USUARIO QUE INGRESAR AL SISTEMA
    int myid, idmyrol, idobjeto;
    String dateinicio, datefin, commentario;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        Date fechaactual = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        //====== ASIGNACION AL VALOR DE LAS VARIABLES CON DATOS DEL USUARIO  ===========//
        try {
            try {
                //====== SESSION PARA  USUARIO QUE INGRESA AL SISTEMA ===========/
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();

                myid = (int) session.getAttribute("ID");

                idmyrol = (int) session.getAttribute("IDROL");
                request.setAttribute("miname", session.getAttribute("NOMBRE"));


            } catch (Exception e) {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

Comment: Necesitas poner al codigo para entender que sucede y poder darte una opinion

Comment: @JGarnica ok, ya lo edite y lo puse en la descripcion

Comment: En los servlets existen dos metodos doGet y  doPost cada vez que llamas/refrescas una pagina el metodo doGet es disparado, generalmente cuado necesitas hacer alguna operacion para persistir datos en la base de datos usas el metodo doPost y no el doGet, estoy casi seguro que estas llamando el metodo processRequest desde el metodo doGET y es por eso que cada vez que refrescas la pagina el proceso se vuelve a ejecutar. espero se entienda mi punto.

Comment: @JGarnica no solo uso uno nunca uso dos. En ese que envíe uso el processrequest en otros solo uso el dopost por ejemplo en el login solo uso el dopost y aún así al refrescar la página me sigue repitiendo la acción de enviar datos